# Send mail script in asp.net with c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Please suggest me a code for **send mail** script in asp.net with **C#**. I want to build **inquiry form** where i wanna send all information on my email Id with attachment, subject and body.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
try
{
    // Assign a sender, recipient and subject to new mail message
    MailAddress sender =
        new MailAddress("sender@johnnycoder.com", "Sender");

    MailAddress recipient =
        new MailAddress("recipient@johnnycoder.com", "Recipient");

    MailMessage m = new MailMessage(sender, recipient);
    m.Subject = "Test Message";

    // Define the plain text alternate view and add to message
    string plainTextBody =
        "You must use an email client that supports HTML messages";

    AlternateView plainTextView =
        AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(
            plainTextBody, null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain);

    m.AlternateViews.Add(plainTextView);

    // Define the html alternate view with embedded image and
    // add to message. To reference images attached as linked
    // resources from your HTML message body, use "cid:contentID"
    // in the <img> tag...
    string htmlBody =
        "<html><body><h1>Picture</h1><br>" +
        "<img src=\"cid:SampleImage\"></body></html>";

    AlternateView htmlView =
        AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(
            htmlBody, null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);

    // ...and then define the actual LinkedResource matching the
    // ContentID property as found in the image tag. In this case,
    // the HTML message includes the tag
    // <img src=\"cid:SampleImage\"> and the following
    // LinkedResource.ContentId is set to "SampleImage"
    LinkedResource sampleImage =
        new LinkedResource("sample.jpg",
            MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg);
    sampleImage.ContentId = "SampleImage";

    htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(sampleImage);

    m.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);

    // Finally, configure smtp or alternatively use the
    // system.net mailSettings
    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient
          {
              Host = "smtp.bigcompany.com",
              UseDefaultCredentials = false,
              Credentials =
                  new NetworkCredential("username", "password")
          };

    //<system.net>
    //    <mailSettings>
    //        <smtp deliveryMethod="Network">
    //            <network host="smtp.bigcompany.com"
    //              port="25" defaultCredentials="true"/>
    //        </smtp>
    //    </mailSettings>
    //</system.net>

    smtp.Send(m);
}
catch (ArgumentException)
{
    throw new
        ArgumentException("Undefined sender and/or recipient.");
}
catch (FormatException)
{
    throw new
        FormatException("Invalid sender and/or recipient.");
}
catch (InvalidOperationException)
{
    throw new
        InvalidOperationException("Undefined SMTP server.");
}
catch (SmtpFailedRecipientException)
{
    throw new SmtpFailedRecipientException(
        "The mail server says that there is no mailbox for recipient");
}
catch (SmtpException ex)
{
    // Invalid hostnames result in a WebException InnerException that
    // provides a more descriptive error, so get the base exception
    Exception inner = ex.GetBaseException();
    throw new SmtpException("Could not send message: " + inner.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This [example](http://www.developer.com/article.php/3096831) shows doing just that. It should cover everything you need.

This [example](http://www.aspheute.com/english/20000918.asp) shows how to add attachments as well, if you need to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Shameless plug:

http://www.SystemNetMail.com

Yeah, it's my site, but it covers about 99% of the things you need to do with System.Net.Mail.